# What's the difference between dried split peas and dried snack peas such as wasabi peas?

Tags: legumes, snacks

Wasabi peas (and similar snacks) appear to just be dried green peas (coated in wasabi).
[image: Wasabi Peas]

Similarly, dried green split peas are also dried green peas (that have been split).
[image: Dried Split Peas]

So why is it that wasabi peas are crispy and edible, while dried split peas are hard like stones?

Comment: p.s. please edit if you can make this clearer or can think of any decent tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recipes for [homemade wasabi peas](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/wasabi-green-peas/) involve soaking, boiling, and then low-temperature roasting (essentially dehydrating) the peas.  [Split peas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_pea) are produced by simply drying the peas after they're harvested and then removing their skins.  So the reason is that the snack peas are cooked while the split peas are essentially raw.  The cooking process breaks down cell walls and makes the peas tender, even after they're roasted to draw out the moisture again.